# When using the remote desktop feature of Gnome, is it possible to lock the local screen when a remote session is active?

Tags: gnome, rdp

I'm trying out the RDP functionality of Gnome 45 and I noticed that the local session is not locked automatically when a remote session is active the way it is on Windows.  Is it possible to have this behavior?

I'm using Arch Linux with the X display server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock local session, then you can run the following command to list all sessions and then find out the session ID for that specific session.

```shellsession
$ loginctl list-sessions

SESSION  UID USER  SEAT  TTY 
      7 1000 user1 seat0 tty2
     c3 1001 user2
```

Now, use the following command to lock that specific session (your local session). In my case, SESSIONID `c3` with `user2` is created from RDP.  I can close local session i.e. 7 (on `tty2`).

```shell
loginctl lock-session SESSIONID
```

**EDIT1: Automate the above task**

- Edit your `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` file and add these entries after your `gnome-session` entry and restart the `xrdp` service.

  ```shell
  sleep 10s
  sudo loginctl lock-session $(loginctl list-sessions | grep seat0 | awk '{print $1}')
  ```
- In order to run passwordless `sudo` command, add the following line to `sudo visudo`.

  ```
  remoteusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/loginctl
  ```

  Now, it will enable passwordless `sudo` for your remote user.

Once your'e in your remote session, it will lock your primary display after 10 seconds.

Comment: If only that could be automated like it is on Windows.

Comment: @DaveF I've not tested this but it should work.


loginctl lock-session $(loginctl list-sessions | grep seat0 | awk '{print $1}')


Add this to /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh file after gnome-session entry. It may work, idk. Give it a try.
seat0 (in the above command) is generally associated with primary display and should work.